# creating test database for Django Unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

How do I populate the test database created while testing the Django test cases with the values from some other database(for ex: the Production database.)

In detail:

when I run the below command,

```
$ python manage.py test
```

a test data base is created for the testing purpose, but it doesn't have any data in it. I want the test database created to be populated with some initial values.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model) to get a file with data from your live db.

Then you can load data from a file automatically for a test (see [Django tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/)):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management import call_command

class Tests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        call_command('loaddata', 'myfile', verbosity=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) to populate your test database.

Create a fixture of your production db and write it to some file

```
python manage.py dumpdata > backup.json
```

You can populate your test database using this command

```
python manage.py loaddata backup.json
```

if you want to do this by running `python manage.py test` then you should write custom [django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out `fixtures`. Here's a link to docs page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

Basically you might want to dump your current database for testing purposes, so you'd do something like:

```
python manage.py dumpdata
```

Then you want to place your file in a directory that Django will look for fixtures. You can either specify it in settings with `FIXTURE_DIRS` variable or use default. The default is simply inside a `fixtures` directory in your Django app.